# CSS class added to multiple li elements on click - How to restrict to clicked li only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a CSS class to a clicked li element in a ul list, but I'm having a problem where the CSS class is being added to multiple li elements instead of the one that was clicked. I want to click on a li, the color applies to the li that clicked Here's the code I'm using:

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.li');
lis.forEach((li)=>{
    li.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        li.classList.add('active')
    })
})
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .li {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .li:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .li.active{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="li">1</li>
        <li class="li">3</li>
        <li class="li">4</li>
        <li class="li">5</li>
        <li class="li">6</li>
        <li class="li">7</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

When I click on an li element, the 'active' class is being added to all li elements in the list who has already clicked, instead of just the one that was clicked. How can I modify this code to ensure that the 'active' class is only added to the clicked li element and not to any others in the list?

Comment: code looks fine to me, and it also seems to be working on your snippet - only the number I click on is turning red

Comment: @RobinZigmond ??? it does not work; it cannot possibly work, as nothing in the code ever removes the class.

Comment: Inside your event callback you could clear the class from every list element and then add the class to the selected element.

Comment: @Pointy you are correct that this code contains no way to remove the class, but that is not what the question is about. The OP clearly states that they are observing the claass being *added* to *all* the items, rather than just the one clicked - which is not actually the case with the code they have shared.

Comment: it's working fine to me as well, if you want to remove `.active` class from other `li`, that's different, which is not mentioned in question.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want

Comment: I have added the answer

Comment: @RobinZigmond well he wrote "... is being added to all li elements in the list who has already clicked, instead of just the one that was clicked." Pretty clear to me.

Comment: It works, but the code is not good and not clear. I am waiting for a better answer. Thank you

Comment: @XMehdi01 What does it mean by more clear? I Just update the provided code inside forEach loop. Its just two to three lines. Can you explain? May be I can help.

Comment: @XMehdi01 If you want more shorter code, then I would recommend you to use jQuery. It will be very helpful.

Comment: no, there is another simple method written in a single line of code

Comment: Yes, we can make it two lines also. The reason I make variables (target and currentActive) is to make code more readable.

Comment: yes I know but I want a code as short as possible

Comment: @XMehdi01 You can write then like this: document.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active') and then next line e.currentTarget.classList.add('active')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the code and use target. And you have to remove active class from previous li.

Here is the full code:

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.li');
lis.forEach((li)=>{
  li.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
      document.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .li {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .li:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .li.active{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li class="li">1</li>
        <li class="li">3</li>
        <li class="li">4</li>
        <li class="li">5</li>
        <li class="li">6</li>
        <li class="li">7</li>
    </ul>
```

The first line:

```
document.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
```

It will select the element that has active class and then it will remove the active class from it. I am using [**?**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which will first check if there is any active element available and if it is available it will remove active class from it. If it's not available it will not throw error.

The second line:

```
e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
```

It will simply add the active class on currently clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

Register the "click" event to a single ancestor element (ie an element that contains all the clickable elements (ex. all `<li>`)). Create an event handler<sup>✱</sup> that will react to specific elements being clicked (ex toggle `".active"` on any `<li>` when clicked). This programming paradigm is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

The behavior of the example is as follows:

- If the user clicks a `<li>` that has `".active"`, remove it, otherwise add `".active"`.
- Only a single `<li>` can have `".active"` at a time.
- If the user clicks anything else, `".active"` will be removed if it exists.

<sup>✱ a function called when a registered event is triggered</sup>

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/*
Register the "click" event to Document Object.
When user clicks anywhere on the page, call setActive().
*/
document.onclick = setActive;

/*
Event handler passes the (event) Object by default.
*/
function setActive(event) {
  /*
  Reference the element that the user clicked.
  */
  const clicked = event.target;
  /*
  Collect all <li> into a NodeList and convert it into an array.
  */
  const liArray = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];
  /*
  Determine the index number of the element the user clicked.
  If the user clicked a <li>, it will be a number between 0 to 6.
  Otherwise it'll be -1.
  */
  let position = liArray.indexOf(clicked);
  /*
  Iterate through 'liArray'... 
  */
  liArray.forEach((li, index) => {
    /*
    If current 'index' DOES NOT EQUAL 'position'...
    */
    if (index !== position) {
      /*
      Remove ".active" from current <li>
      */
      li.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });

  /*
  If the element the user clicked is a <li>...
  */
  if (clicked.matches("li")) {
    /*
    ...add/remove (ie toggle) ".active" to it.
    */
    clicked.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1.2 "Segoe UI";
}

ul {
  width: min-content;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

li {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.active {
  outline: 3px solid cyan;
  color: cyan;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.li');
lis.forEach((li)=>{
  li.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
      document.querySelector('.active')?.classList.remove('active');
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .li {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .li:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .li.active{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li class="li">1</li>
        <li class="li">3</li>
        <li class="li">4</li>
        <li class="li">5</li>
        <li class="li">6</li>
        <li class="li">7</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that want to set active just the clicked item you can just change your js code like this

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.li');
const setActive= (li) => {
    Array.from(lis).forEach((item) => {
        item.classList.remove("active");
    });
    li.classList.add('active')
}
lis.forEach((li)=>{
    li.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        setActive(li)
    })
})
```

Comment: 1. Using extra foreach loop. You can directly remove the active using querySelector and it will remove. 2. Don't need array.Form because you can use foreach loop directly on NodeList. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: It works but the code is not clear there is an easier way than this

Answer (score 0):

As per your original question, your code is working as expected.

Based on your comment, where you want to remove `.active` class from previous `li`, Try this:

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.li');
lis.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // remove active class from all li
    lis.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
    
    // add active to current li
    li.classList.add('active')
    
  })
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.li {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="li">1</li>
    <li class="li">3</li>
    <li class="li">4</li>
    <li class="li">5</li>
    <li class="li">6</li>
    <li class="li">7</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove the class of the selected li

```
document.querySelector('li.active')?.classList.remove('active');
li.classList.add('active');
```

Or you can just use html and css and avoid JavaScript alltogether.

```css
ul.pages {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.pages li label{
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.pages li:hover label{
  background-color: #ccc;
}

ul.pages input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}

ul.pages input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pages">
  <li><input type="radio" name="pg" id="pg1"><label for="pg1">1</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="pg" id="pg2"><label for="pg2">2</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="pg" id="pg3"><label for="pg3">3</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="pg" id="pg4"><label for="pg4">4</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="pg" id="pg5"><label for="pg5">5</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="pg" id="pg6"><label for="pg6">6</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="pg" id="pg7"><label for="pg7">7</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class from the current `li.active` (if it exists). Here is a solution using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), so you need one handler function.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

// For fun: the advantage of event delegation is that 
// you're able to add elements without having to assign 
// a new handler to it.
insertMissing();

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.closest(`li`)) {
    document.querySelector(`li.active`)?.classList.remove(`active`);
    return evt.target.closest(`li`).classList.add(`active`);
  }

  return true;
}

function insertMissing() {
  const nwLi = Object.assign(
    document.createElement(`li`), {
      className: `li`,
      innerHTML: `<b>2</b>`
    });
  document.querySelector(`ul li:first-child`)
    .insertAdjacentElement(`afterend`, nwLi);
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.li {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li">1</li>
  <li class="li">3</li>
  <li class="li">4</li>
  <li class="li">5</li>
  <li class="li">6</li>
  <li class="li">7</li>
</ul>
```