# why doesn't the buttons let me toggle through the sections?

Tags: javascript, html

I was building a portfolio website using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I encountered an error:

> *Uncaught type Error allSections.addEventListener is not a function.*

I was trying to toggle between the sections of the website using the buttons but they get stuck with the first section, the button clicks don't take them to the next section.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');


function PageTransitions() {
  //buttonclickactiveclass
  for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
    sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
      currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');
      this.className += 'active-btn';
    })
  }
  //sections active class
  allSections.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    if (id) {
      //remove selected from the other btns
      sectBtns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active')
      })
      e.target.classList.add('active')

      //hide other class
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        section.classList.remove('active')
      })

      const element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.classList.add('active');
    }
  })

}
PageTransitions();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body class="main-content">
  <header class="section sec1 header active" data-id="home">

  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="section sec2 about" id="about"></section>
    <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio"></section>
    <section class="section sec4 blogs" id="blogs"></section>
    <section class="section sec5 contact" id="contact"></section>
  </main>

  <div class="controls">
    <div class="control control-1 active-btn" data-id="home">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-2 " data-id="about">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-3 " data-id="portfolio">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-4 " data-id="blogs">
      <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-5 " data-id="contact">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

i tried to pass a console.log function but it didnt work too. im hoping someone can help me with this.

Comment: `allSections` is a NodeList, not an element. You'll have to loop through each element in the collection and add an event listener to each individually. You can't add event listeners to a NodeList.

Comment: @sean It is not an HTML Collection object but a Node List. `querySelectorAll` returns a node list. But the solution is pretty much the same by using a `forEach` iteration.

Comment: i was actually following a freecodecamp tutorial but this code worked for him.

Comment: Either the tutorial is incorrect or this code doesn't match the tutorial. Is it possible the fourth line in the JS is supposed to be `querySelector` and not `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: @sidharth23 Look at this answer. You will understand the errors in your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76200326/css-class-added-to-multiple-li-elements-on-click-how-to-restrict-to-clicked-li/76200369#76200369

Comment: @sidharth23 I have concise and update your code. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` does not return a single element but a `node list`. Simply use `console.log(allSection)` or `console.log(typeof allSection)` and see what it returns. The simple solution is to use a `forEach` iteration to apply the `eventListener` to all the elements within the node list:

```js
allSection.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    ...
  })
)
```

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');


function PageTransitions() {
  //buttonclickactiveclass
  for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
    sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
      currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');
      this.className += 'active-btn';
    })
  }
  //sections active class
  allSections.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    if (id) {
      //remove selected from the other btns
      sectBtns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active')
      })
      e.target.classList.add('active')

      //hide other class
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        section.classList.remove('active')
      })

      const element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.classList.add('active');
    }
  }))

}
PageTransitions();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body class="main-content">
  <header class="section sec1 header active" data-id="home">

  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="section sec2 about" id="about"></section>
    <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio"></section>
    <section class="section sec4 blogs" id="blogs"></section>
    <section class="section sec5 contact" id="contact"></section>
  </main>

  <div class="controls">
    <div class="control control-1 active-btn" data-id="home">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-2 " data-id="about">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-3 " data-id="portfolio">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-4 " data-id="blogs">
      <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-5 " data-id="contact">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's only one `.main-content` element, and based on the name I'm guessing there's only ever going to be one and they meant to use `.querySelector()` instead of `.querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 0):

You are **selecting all sections with querySelectorAll()**. It will return a **NodeList** which contain list of sections. So, you have to **loop over them** and then you can use **addEventListener()**.

There are **lot of mistakes and extra code**. I have updated the code based on your requirement. Try that:-

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');

function PageTransitions(){
    sections.forEach(section => {
      section.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        const target = e.target;
        const id = target.getAttribute('id');
        if(id){
         // Update active for Section
         document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
         target.classList.add('active')
         // Update active for Control
         document.querySelector('.active-btn').classList.remove('active-btn');
         document.querySelector('div[data-id="' + id + '"]').classList.add('active-btn')
        }
      });
    })
 
}
PageTransitions();
```

```css
main{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.active{
background-color: red;
}

.active-btn{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body class="main-content">
    <main>
    <header class="section sec1 header active" id="home">
         Home Logo
    </header>
        <section class="section sec2 about" id="about">About</section>
        <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio">Portfolio</section>
        <section class="section sec4 blogs" id="blogs">Blogs</section>
        <section class="section sec5 contact" id="contact">Contact</section>
    </main>

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="control control-1 active-btn" data-id="home">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-2 " data-id="about">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-3 " data-id="portfolio">
            <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-4 " data-id="blogs">
            <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-5 " data-id="contact">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I used some lines of CSS for showing the active section and control. Hope it will be helpful.